# How to import the same file two times in a row in html and typescript?

Tags: html, typescript

I have an input element in html file like this:

```
 <input
   type="file"
   (change)="receiveFile($event)"
   id="inputFileButton"
   hidden
 />
```

And it's waiting for user to import file. On button click I call uploadFile() method which emits event on input element which calls receiveFile($event). Like this:

```
  receiveFile($event) {
  const fileFromHtml = $event.target.files[0];
  const importedFile: FormData = new FormData();
  importedFile.append('positions', fileFromHtml);
   this.store.dispatch({
    type: '[Position] Import Positions',
    importFile: importedFile,
    positionSetId: this.positionSetId,
    accountSetId: this.accountSetId,
   });
  }

  uploadFile() {
   this.testvar = !this.testvar;
   const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(
     'inputFileButton',
   ) as HTMLElement;
   element.click();
  }
```

It works fine except for the case when I want to import the same file two times in a row. The second time it doesn's call at all receiveFile($event).

Comment: because your file does not change. Why would you expect your code to rerun? What is the purpose?

Comment: because when I import a file I get some data from it, and next time I want also to get data from file nevermind it's duplicated. maybe there is a way to restart input field idk

Comment: You could reset the input in between the calls. Or just chain you logic without depending on another click

Comment: how to reset it :)

Comment: Or use the `input` event perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your receiveFile() function only runs on the change event. If the same file is inputted, nothing has changed, so it doesn't run.

To overcome this, you can try clearing your input

```
document.getElementById("inputFileButton").value = ''
```